# gulp rename file in same directory

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

I'm trying to minify and then create a copy without the "src." part of every index.src.php file inside any folder so I still have index.src.php available but a minified copy index.php:

```
gulp.task('usemin', function() {
    return gulp.src('./**/index.src.php')
        .pipe(usemin({
            inlinecss: [ minifyCss, 'concat' ]
        }))
        .pipe(rename(function(path){
            path.basename = path.basename.replace('min\.', '');
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

... so far this only literally renames the index.src.php into index.php

Answer (score 3):

gulp-rename was easier than expected...

```
gulp.task('usemin', function() {
    return gulp.src('./**/index.src.php')
        .pipe(usemin({
            inlinecss: [ minifyCss, 'concat' ]
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
            basename: 'index'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```